# Custom TCP wire protocol into RabbitMQ

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq

I have a VERY dumb, slow embedded device which currently sends a tiny, custom TCP message to a TCP socket on a server.

I want to change how the server works, and am looking at a message broker. Can I give RabbitMQ a custom TCP stream definition or some code that handles it, or does it only speak AMQP and I have to go for a different solution (e.g. a tiny socket server written in C that consumes TCP and spits out AMQP).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ only speaks AMQP, so the answer is no.

That said, any data can be transmitted as message payloads in AMQP, so feel free to bridge to your app that way. You'll need an "AMQP->your TCP needs" translation layer though.

Comment: Thanks Brian - that's what I suspected :)